# Replace PHP variables in Mysql Fetch string

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I stored dynamic links in database like this

```
http://{$site}.com/{$username}
```

and in PHP file

```
$site = google.com;$username = 2;
```

But when i fetch from db it dont replace with php variable it simply output as

```
http://{$site}.com/{$username}
```

I tried `preg_replace('/\{\$([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)\}/e', "$$1", $row['url']);`
But it replace only one variable in mysql fetched string other remains static.

So is there another way to do replace all values in `{}` with specific php variables.

Comment: `$site` is not a valid string. Perhaps you should enable error_reporting first..

Comment: $site is for example only to tell you people my problem

Answer (score 0):

you are getting data as a string so var value not replacing

```
http://{$site}.com/{$username} 
// not varable {$site} and {$username}
```

this is a string

try to insert full url or try

simply use when outputing:-

[str_replace](https://www.php.net/str_replace)

```
$tmpurl = str_replace('{$site}', $site, $row['url']);
$url = str_replace('{$username}', $username, $tmpurl);
```

Comment: i have to add str_replace again and again to replace all variable is there other way to replace all variable at once. preg_replace to variable at once but stop after that i dont know why

Comment: try str_replace in your data fatching loop

Comment: bro str_replace will replace one thing at a time, i want to make it dynamic, not one by one at once all of them

Comment: Then loop through the data and str_replace where necessary..  

$select = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT url FROM settings");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select))
 $url = str_replace(array('{$site}', '{$username}'), array($site, $username), $row['url']);